# How can i insert one array list of data to another array list which some fields are same?

Tags: java, arraylist, comparison, conventions

I am stuck with small problem.I have two ArrayLists and I want to compare some values in the ArrayLists.

```
List<TriangleInfo> arrayList = dataGridTable.selectLastvalueNoAverage(equipid);
```

if fire this query i have get one arraylist.

```
public List<TriangleInfo> selectLastvalueNoAverage(int equipid)
    {
        List<TriangleInfo> list = new ArrayList<TriangleInfo>();

        cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.DGADATATABLE, columns, "equipid = '"+equipid+"' ", null, null,null, "dateadded DESC");

        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            triangleInfo = new TriangleInfo();

            triangleInfo.setDgaid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.DGAID)));
            triangleInfo.setDateadded(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.DATEADDED)));
            triangleInfo.setCh4(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CH4)));
            triangleInfo.setC2h2(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.C2H2)));
            triangleInfo.setC2h4(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.C2H4)));

            list.add(triangleInfo);
        }

        cursor.close();

    return list;
}
```

In the same way the second query is

```
List<ThresholdsInfo> Threshold = thresholdsTable.selectAllRecords();
```

Here also I get one ArrayList.

```
public List<ThresholdsInfo> selectAllRecords()
    {
        List<ThresholdsInfo> list = new ArrayList<ThresholdsInfo>();
        cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.THRESHOLDS, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            info = new ThresholdsInfo();

            info.setThresholdid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.THRESHOLDID)));
            info.setH2(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.H2)));
            info.setCh4(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CH4)));
            info.setC2h2(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.C2H2)));
            info.setC2h4(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.C2H4)));
            info.setC2h6(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.C2H6)));
            info.setCo(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CO)));
            info.setCo2(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CO2)));
            info.setO2(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.O2)));
            info.setN2(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.N2)));
            info.setTdcg(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TDCG)));

            list.add(info);
        }
        cursor.close();

        return list;
    }
```

So my problem is I have to compare the ch4,c2h2,c2h6 values in both ArrayList. So I did like

```
public String ThresholdCheck(List<TriangleInfo> arrayList)
    {
        thresholdsTable = new ThresholdsTable(context);
        int ch4=0,tch4=0;

        String color = "Black";
        List<ThresholdsInfo> Threshold = thresholdsTable.selectAllRecords();


        for(TriangleInfo info : arrayList)
        {
            info.getC2h2();
        }

        for(ThresholdsInfo info : Threshold)
        {
            tch4 = info.getCh4();
        }

        if(ch4>=tch4)
        {

        }
        return color;
    }
```

I wrote like that but that is long procedure. Please tell me is there any simple solution.

Comment: your for loops are going to loop through the whole arrayList and get the value of the last elment.  I don't think this is what you want to do.

Comment: In the ThresholdsInfo info i have only one record. And TriangleInfo have some records. I want every time color for every record of the TriangleInfo.